# How do I make a moving structure with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So. I am trying to make a boat move in minecraft. I don't want all those noisy pistons and stuff, and I want to make it move like one block at a time I don't know how to use the clone command. Does anyone know how to make my boat move one block a time?, like the command. What command do I have to put because whenever I try I move it one block forward and to make the previous structure disappear. I want it to move 1 block at a time constantly. Anyone know how to do this, or the command?

Comment: By "boat" do you mean a Minecraft boat (the kind that you craft with wood that players can ride in), or do you mean a larger boat that you've built yourself with blocks? I sort of think you mean a large boat, but I'd like to know for sure, because my answer would be very different, depending.

Comment: I mean a very large boat that I make with blocks.

Answer (score 3):

First place the following command in a normal (impulse) command block *inside* the boat, attached to a simple [clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock_circuit). The speed of the clock will determine the speed the boat moves.

```
/clone ~<x1> ~<y1> ~<z1> ~<x2> ~<y2> ~<z2> ~<x3> ~ ~<z3> replace move
```

To calculate the values:

x1 is the number of blocks in the *negative* x direction from the command block to the edge of the boat, not including the command block, multiplied by -1.

y1 is the number of blocks in the *negative* y direction from the command block to the bottom of the boat, not including the command block, multiplied by -1.

z1 is the number of blocks in the *negative* z direction from the command block to the edge of the boat, not including the command block, multiplied by -1.

x2 is the number of blocks in the *positive* x direction from the command block to the edge of the boat, not including the command block.

y2 is the number of blocks in the *positive* y direction from the command block to the top of the boat, not including the command block.

z2 is the number of blocks in the *positive* z direction from the command block to the edge of the boat, not including the command block.

If you want the boat to move in the *positive* x direction then x3 = 1, z3 = 0.

If you want the boat to move in the *negative* x direction then x3 = -1, z3 = 0.

If you want the boat to move in the *positive* z direction then x3 = 0, z3 = 1.

If you want the boat to move in the *negative* z direction then x3 = 0, z3 = -1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I put the exact thing when I wanted to put it -1 (negative x), replace and move and it said source and destination cannot overlap. Help!

Comment: You still need to put the ~ if the value is zero, for example in the <z3> spot.

Answer (score 1):

First place the following command in a normal (impulse) command block inside the boat, attached to a simple clock. The speed of the clock will determine the speed the boat moves.

/clone ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ replace move
To calculate the values:

x1 is the number of blocks in the negative x direction from the command block to the edge of the boat, not including the command block, multiplied by -1.

y1 is the number of blocks in the negative y direction from the command block to the bottom of the boat, not including the command block, multiplied by -1.

z1 is the number of blocks in the negative z direction from the command block to the edge of the boat, not including the command block, multiplied by -1.

x2 is the number of blocks in the positive x direction from the command block to the edge of the boat, not including the command block.

y2 is the number of blocks in the positive y direction from the command block to the top of the boat, not including the command block.

z2 is the number of blocks in the positive z direction from the command block to the edge of the boat, not including the command block.

If you want the boat to move in the positive x direction then x3 = 1, z3 = 0.

If you want the boat to move in the negative x direction then x3 = -1, z3 = 0.

If you want the boat to move in the positive z direction then x3 = 0, z3 = 1.

If you want the boat to move in the negative z direction then x3 = 0, z3 = -1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yee it’s possible,

You can just add a command block if you want the boat to move in any directions at will, you can have a floor that’s like a D pad using pressure plates.

And under the plates there would be the command blocks

Left plate would be:
/clone (cordinates from start of ship) (cordinates from the end of the ship) ^1 ^(cord1-cord2) ^0 replace move

Right plate would be:
/clone (cordinates from start of ship) (cordinates from the end of the ship) ^-1 ^(cord1-cord2) ^0 replace move

Top plate would be:
/clone (cordinates from start of ship) (cordinates from the end of the ship) ^0 ^(cord1-cord2) ^1 replace move

Back plate would be:
/clone (cordinates from start of ship) (cordinates from the end of the ship) ^0 ^(cord1-cord2) ^-1 replace move

Note, make sure the start’s y cordinates is lower than the end’s y cordinate, and the x, y, and z cordinates cover each block

(So if there was blocks in 1 5 8 through 3 6 5, I would use
“/clone 1 5 8 3 6 5 ^0 ^-1 ^1 replace move”

Edit: if the left and right ones don’t work, swap the negatives/positives on x cords (so it would have ^-1 and the other one would have ^1)